# How to clean an stone-stricken carbon MTB without doing damage to the carbon....?

Tags: carbon

My carbon MTB have got some damage (not cracks) to the paint from stones from the wheels, so I want to clean the damaged specks out, and put on som protection.

First of all, will it damage the carbon if I clean out the specks with benzine or oil, and then afterwards use some de-greaser, I do suspect some of the specks does go all the way in to the carbon-frame itself....

Second, after having cleaned the frame I want to put on some protection, I have thought about buying some dedicated folium for it, but have also thought about just putting on some gaffertape.

-So my question is, will the glue on the gaffertape do damage to the carbon....?

Bjarke

Comment: If they're just stones, solvents will be no better than water - so start with water, then think about whether there's grease to get off

Comment: Be careful when using solvents on a carbon frame or on paint in general. Most instruction booklets that come with carbon frames will tell you to refrain from using solvents and just the surfaces with water and soap.

Comment: On the other hand, the oil/grease (of which there is some, I have been way too lazy with regards to cleaning) is in itself an solvent, and I might be better off getting it away before I put on protection....?

Answer (score 4):

I would clean the area with soap and water. you can cover any deep paint chips  with clear nail polish. Gaffers tape which I assume is similar to  duct tape will not provide adequate protection. It degrades when exposed to sunlight and the residue left after it is removed is tough to  remove. There are several companies making frame protection films. "Lizard Skins" is one I am familiar with. It is a thick  plastic  adhesive backed film. The film comes in precut shapes to mount in specific areas. When the film gets to the point it needs replacement it peels off. Any glue residue comes off with alcohol.